# Mean and SD in a table

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

In R, when doing table of two variables, you'll get a frequency table

```
> table(data$Var1, data$Var2)

     1  2  3  4  5
  0  0  1  5  6 12
  1  1 10  6  7  0
  2  2  6  7  6  3
  3  2  9  8  3  2
  4  4  9  5  3  3
  5  3  4  9  4  4
  6  2  7  7  4  4
  7  2  7  7  6  2
  8  5  7  5  5  2
  9  5  4  5  6  4
```

is there a way such that you include the `mean` and `SD` in each row, something like

```
     1  2  3  4  5  mean     SD
  0  0  1  5  6 12  4.20833  0.93153
  1  1 10  6  7  0  ..       ..
  2  2  6  7  6  3
  3  2  9  8  3  2
  4  4  9  5  3  3
  5  3  4  9  4  4
  6  2  7  7  4  4
  7  2  7  7  6  2
  8  5  7  5  5  2
  9  5  4  5  6  4
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg wont that compute the sd of the data *and* the mean? It looks wrong....

Comment: @DavidArenburg Needs list of lists, eg: `addmargins(m,2,FUN=list(list(mean,sd)))` I think...

Comment: @DavidArenburg help(addmargins) is quite the twisty turny maze of functional passages. Sometimes simple is best (see my answer!).

Comment: Thanks all, maybe I have should've made it more clearer. The table is a frequency table, so the mean is not just the sum of the row divided by the number of columns, it's the sum of the frequencies / number of occurances. So in the first row it should be (1*0 + 2*1 + 3*5 + 4*6 + 5*12) / number of element

Comment: @ZheyuanLi my bad. I edited my previous comment. The mean should be (1*0 + 2*1 + 3*5 + 4*6 + 5*12) / number of element = 24  and SD would be 0.93153

Comment: For the mean you could do `colSums(t(m) * as.integer(colnames(m)))/rowSums(m)` (if your table called `m`) though I don't think that using column names as integers is a good practice

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit tricker to get the SD, haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Save the table in something called `T`, and then:

For the mean and sd:

```
> cbind(T,
  mean=apply(T,1,function(x){
   (sum(x*(1:5)))/sum(x)}),
  sd=apply(T,1,function(x){sd(rep(1:5,x))}))

  1 2 3 4 5     mean        sd
0 4 3 1 1 1 2.200000 1.3984118
1 1 2 3 3 3 3.416667 1.3113722
2 2 2 1 2 1 2.750000 1.4880476
3 0 1 2 4 1 3.625000 0.9161254
```

So 2.2 and 1.3984 is mean and sd of (c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5))

Its probably inefficient to compute the sd by reconstructing the original vector with `rep` - but its late and working out all the sums of squares and squares of sums for the sd is not something my brain can do at 1am.

Comment: Thanks, but this would add the values of the row and divide by 5 to get the mean. The table is a frequency table, so your example the mean of the first row is 3.14286 because we have 1,1,2,4,4,5,5.

Comment: @MustafaS where are you getting 1,1,2,4,4,5,5 from? I get 1.4 as the first mean because thats the mean of 2,1,0,2,2. (7/5).

Comment: @Spacedman - for the first row there are two 1's, one 2, zero 3's, two 4's and two 5's I think. They are expanding the values in the table and then taking the mean.

Comment: @thelatemail my bad. It should be (1*2 + 2*1 + 3*0 + 4*0 + 5 *2 ) / 7 because at row 0, there are 7 total elements, and we have two 1's, one 2, zero 3's, two 4's and two 5's .